# GDB pretty printer subclass info

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, clion

I use the Clion IDE and VS Code for C++ developement and debugging, and I noticed a difference, which drives me crazy. In case I have a vector of pointers to subclasses, the Clion shows me the type of the subclass but VS Code does not. Here's the simplest code which I can reproduce the effect:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class A {
protected:
    int x;
public:
    A(int x) : x(x) {}

    virtual std::string to_str() { return std::to_string(x); }
};

class B : public A {
    int y;
public:
    B(int x, int y) : A(x), y(y) {}

    std::string to_str() override { return std::to_string(x) + '_' + std::to_string(y); }
};

class C : public A {
    std::string z;
public:
    C(int x, std::string z) : A(x), z(z) {}

    std::string to_str() override { return std::to_string(x) + '_' + z; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<B>(2, 3));
    v.push_back(std::make_shared<C>(4,"5"));

    for(auto &elem : v) {
        std::cout << elem->to_str() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Without the virtual function there is no info about the subclass. Both Clion and VS Code use the same compiler and gdb.
Placeing a breakpoint inside the for and executing in gdb console:
`p *elem.get()` I get `$1 = {_vptr.A = 0x40fc70 <vtable for B+16>, x = 2}` however in Clion I get `$1 = (B) {<A> = {_vptr.A = 0x40fc70 <vtable for B+16>, x = 2}, y = 3}`.

Listing the configuration of GDB shows no difference (same gdbinit), also listing the pretty-printers has some difference but nothing stands out.

My guess is that Clion add a special printer, but the result is the same if I turn off the library renderers. I tried this on Windows (mingw64 GCC 8.2) and Linux (GCC 7.3) too, same result.

I checked the GDB pretty-printer documentation, but it's not very useful so I didn't try to write one.
Is there a special pretty-printer to show the subclass type and members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show the actual type of the object, CLion enables the `print object` setting of GDB, which is described in the GDB manual as:

> ```
> set print object
> set print object on
> ```
>
> When displaying a pointer to an object, identify the actual (derived) type of the object rather than the declared type, using the virtual function table. Note that the virtual function table is required — this feature can only work for objects that have run-time type identification; a single virtual method in the object’s declared type is sufficient.

This behavior is enabled when starting a debug session using GDB, there's no way to disable it, except from the GDB console view in CLion:

```
(gdb) set print object off
```